# Is it possible to gather rows created during statement execution?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm looking for something that'll effectivley to this: `ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Table (num1,num2,num3) VALUES (1,2,3)").execute();`

Essentially setting data on the rows you've created to a variable. Obviousily ResultSet only works for SELECT, but I was wondering if there's a way to farm the rows created rather than performing a separate query to locate them. If there's a way to do this, I've been unable to find it.

Comment: What is the source of the values being inserted? Are you applying literal INSERT statements that already have the values embedded in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL there is no result set generated for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE statements.

MySQL does not support the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) found in Microsoft SQL Server.

A workaround that would work in MySQL (though only for single-row INSERT) is to execute the INSERT with user variable assignments embedded into the VALUES clause.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (num1, num2, num3) VALUES (@num1:=1, @num2:=2, @num3:=3)
```

This still won't create a result set for the INSERT statement, so you'll have to execute a SELECT query subsequent to the INSERT.

```
SELECT @num1 AS num1, @num2 AS num2, @num3 AS num3
```

Another workaround is to do the assignment to user variables inside an INSERT TRIGGER. You wouldn't have to do the assignment in the VALUES clause that way. But you'd still have to SELECT the user variables after the INSERT is done. This would also work only for a single-row INSERT.